# Python: insert 2D array into MySQL table

Tags: python, mysql, arrays, python-2.7

I have database named : test; table named: cord;
rows named: id ;  x ; y ; z.

Lets say i have 2d array like this:

```
asd = [[1.25,2.45,3.65],[2.78,3.59,1.58]......]
```

I want to insert asd[0][0] element into x row, asd [0][1] into y row, asd[0][2] into z row, asd [1][0] into x row, asd[1][1] into y row, asd [1][2] into z row and etc if i have more aray elements.

My code so far(i know that insert function defines only x):

```
import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",port= 3307,user="root",passwd="usbw" , db = "test")

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cur = db.cursor()

# Create table as per requirement
 asd = [[1.25,2.45,3.65],[2.78,3.59,1.58]]
 for x in asd:
 cur.execute("INSERT INTO cord(x) VALUES(%s)",x)
 db.commit()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that "in one go" via `executemany()`:

```
cur.executemany("""
    INSERT INTO 
        cord
        (x, y, z)
    VALUES
        (%s, %s, %s)
""", asd)
db.commit()
```